# Is there a way to set up a kafka server on Android?

Tags: android, apache-kafka, neural-network, android-architecture-components

My goal is to feed a NN on Android with real time streaming events from various data sources (sensors, other servers). I have created a working set up on a linux server with Kafka to explore the concept. Replicating this set up to an Android device poses the question if this is the correct architecture for a mobile device as well, or if I should go for a completely different approach.

Comment: Although you don't provide a lot of information about what are you trying to achieve and what data needs to be exchanged between the server and the client, I would argue that installing Kafka on Android doesn't sound right me (and I am not even sure you can actually configure Kafka on an Android device - I don't think you can). Why don't you just go with a `REST`ful approach?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka on Android does not work (server especially, but client neither), and is not recommended due to required network connections.

More commonly, MQTT is used for streaming mobile and IOT sensor devices (which could in-turn send data to Kafka at the backend, collection site)